# Is there a formula or method to calculate precisely the length of a tropical year at any given time?

Tags: geophysics

I am aware of [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year#Mean_tropical_year_current_value), but it is very limited, as it is only

> an expression suitable for calculating the length of a tropical year in ephemeris days, between 8000 BC and 12000 AD.

Comment: What makes that formula not useful to you?  If imprecise, what precision are you looking for?  If the range, what range are you looking for?

Comment: @BowlOfRed The range. I am looking for all time ranges where there has been a earth surrounding the sun. Or let's add at least +/- 10^6 years to that range.